# How to retrieve a row in a database and convert it into an object in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to learn how to do CRUD operations in Spring 2.5.6. I made a table in my database called companies that has 2 fields: id and name. What I want to do is to retrieve a row from the table using the id field. This is what I made for it.

```
public class JdbcCompanyDao extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport implements CompanyDao {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public Company getCompany(int id) {
        logger.info("Getting company with id = " + id);
        Company company = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
                "SELECT id, name FROM companies WHERE id = " + id,
                new CompanyMapper());
        return company;
    }

    private static class CompanyMapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<Company> {
        public Company mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Company company = new Company();
            company.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            company.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            return company;
        }
    }
}
```

I made a unit test for it to check if I did it right:

```
public class JdbcCompanyDaoTests extends AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests {
    private CompanyDao companyDao;

    public void setCompanyDao(CompanyDao companyDao) {
        this.companyDao = companyDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getConfigLocations() {
        return new String[] {"classpath:test-context.xml"};
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetUpInTransaction() throws Exception {
        super.deleteFromTables(new String[] {"companies"});
        super.executeSqlScript("file:db/load_data.sql", true);
    }

    public void testGetCompany() {
        Company company = companyDao.getCompany(1);

        assertEquals("SomeRandomCompany", company.getName());
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

> org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException:
>   Incorrect result size: expected 1,
>   actual 0

I can't find the reason why *getCompany()* is returning an empty result set. Right now, I have no idea what I need to do and I'm still confused about how Spring works. Does it have something to do with how *AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests* works?

Side question: Are there any good resources that demonstrates how to do CRUD operations in Spring? So far, the only resources I have are [this](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/index.html) and [this](http://maestric.com/doc/java/spring) and they don't really provide enough examples for me get anything going on.

Comment: Does it work if you change onSetUpInTransaction() to onSetUp()?

Comment: @Ritesh, nope. I just follow what I see in the tutorial (http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/index.html) and try to add some of my own. Everything from the tutorial works except for my test method. In case you're wondering, I sliced off the other methods from both classes when I pasted it to this question since they work, kind of irrelevant and are part of the tutorial.

Comment: why do you start with Spring 2.5 now when Spring 3 is already over a year old?

Comment: @Sean, I couldn't find a good tutorial for Spring 3 so I settled for 2.5 because it has a tutorial at the website. Can you point me to some? Ones with demonstrations on CRUD operations will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `select.queryForList` method from spring.  Hopefully an example will help.

From the spring configuration xml file, you define your data source.  Pretty much any valid select statement will work.  Use this as a starting point for what you want.

```
<bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="${mysql.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${mysql.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${mysql.password}"/>
</bean>
```

The actual method used to retrieve the data is really quite simple...

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> showTables() {

    String sql = "select name from MYTABLE..sysobjects where xtype = 'U';";

    JdbcTemplate select = new JdbcTemplate(sqlDataSource);

    return select.queryForList(sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `getSimpleJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(...)` is assuming that it finds *exactly* one row with given query and raises exception otherwise. Are you sure that your database contains a row with parameter `id=1`?

You should use parametrized version of `queryForObject()` instead of concatenating query string with the parameters, for example.

```
getSimpleJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
            "SELECT id, name FROM companies WHERE id = ?",
            new CompanyMapper(), id)
```